# Angular change component if user is logged in doesn't work as expected

Tags: angular

I have an Angular project and my goal is to display certain data depending on whenever user is logged in or not. I'm using [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51352673/angular-6-change-component-if-user-is-logged-in/51352797) but I keep getting this error `Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'` Here is my auth.serveice relevant part:

```
private currentUserSubject: BehaviorSubject<User>;
private user = new Subject<any>();
public currentUser: Observable<User>;
public userEmitter = this.user.asObservable();
userEmitChange(user: any) {
    this.user.next(user);
}

logIn(identifier: string, password: string) {
  return this.http.post<any>(`${environment.apiUrl}/auth/local`, { identifier, password })
    .pipe(map(user => {
      // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
      localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
      this.userEmitChange(user);
      this.currentUserSubject.next(user);
      this.currentUser = this.currentUserSubject.asObservable();
      return user;
    }));
}
```

My home component where data will be displayed:

```
user: any = null;

constructor(
  private researcherService: ResearcherService,
  private authService: AuthService,
  private router: Router,
  private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.authService.userEmitter.subscribe(user => {
      this.user = user;
    });
    this.user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
  }
```

And my html part:

```
<p class="research-card_name" *ngIf="user | async; else guestName">{{researcher?.contact_person}}</p>
<ng-template #guestName><p class="research-card_name">Name</p></ng-template>
```

Not sure where the error is and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using async pipe ?

Comment: To show field value depending if the user is logged in, I don't want to use guard here because component should be visible for both logined and not logined users

Comment: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')) is not an observable, so you cannot use the async pipe for this.user. Try without the pipe

Answer (score 0):

Remove `async` pipe. You can't use `async` pipe in your case as your `user` is neither `Observable` or `Promise`.

From docs:

> The async pipe subscribes to an Observable or Promise and returns the
> latest value it has emitted. When a new value is emitted, the async
> pipe marks the component to be checked for changes. When the component
> gets destroyed, the async pipe unsubscribes automatically to avoid
> potential memory leaks.

Refer to this [link](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) for more details.